# Project Euler #12 in Scala — Highly divisible triangular numbers

Tags: programming-challenge, scala

I generally work in Python for programming competitions, but I'm teaching myself Scala. As an exercise, I've attempted [Project Euler problem #12](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12) in Scala. I hope that somebody familiar with Scala can point out anything I'm doing which is not idiomatic in "functional style" Scala. My code produces the correct result, and is reasonably fast, so I'm mostly looking for coding style advice.

```
object HighlyDivisibleTriangularNumber {
  val triangleCache = collection.mutable.Map[Int, Int]()
  val triangle: Int => Int = {
    case 1 => 1
    case n => triangle(n - 1) + n
  }
  def cachedTriangle(n: Int) = triangleCache.getOrElseUpdate(n, triangle(n))

  def nFactors(x: Int): Int = {
    val maxFactor: Int = math.round(math.sqrt(x.floatValue).floatValue)
    val smallFactors: Set[Int] = (1 to maxFactor).filter(f => x % f == 0).toSet
    val allFactors: Set[Int] = smallFactors ++ smallFactors.map(f => x / f)
    allFactors.size
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val triangleNumbers = Iterator.from(1).map(cachedTriangle)
    val firstWith500Factors = triangleNumbers.dropWhile(nFactors(_) < 500).next
    println(firstWith500Factors)
  }
}
```

I realize that a mutable collection is not a great starting point for functional Scala, but struggled to implement a memoized version of `triangle` without the mutable map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your triangular number "cache" isn't an idiomatic technique in functional programming.  Since triangular numbers constitute an infinite sequence, it would be more elegant to model them in Scala as an infinite lazy stream, especially since you only require sequential access.  I would define it this way:

```
val triangleNumbers = Stream.from(1).scan(0)(_ + _)
```

Or, if you prefer to have the sequence start with 1 rather than 0:

```
val triangleNumbers = Stream.from(2).scan(1)(_ + _)
```

---

`nFactors` could be optimized a bit.

- I would call the parameter `n`, which has the connotation of being an integer, instead of `x`, which has the connotation of being floating point.
- The `.floatValue` casts are superfluous, and it is safe to round the square root down using `.intValue` rather than sometimes rounding up.
- Personally, I would prefer the name `middleFactor` instead of `maxFactor`.
- The lambda in `.filter(f => x % f == 0)` could be more idiomatically written as `.filter(x % _ == 0)`.
- You don't need to use sets.  Just a count of factors will do, along with a check of whether `middleFactor` is being double-counted.

```
def nFactors(n: Int): Int = {
  val middleFactor = math.sqrt(n).intValue
  val smallFactors = (1 to middleFactor).count(n % _ == 0)
  2 * smallFactors - (if (middleFactor * middleFactor == n) 1 else 0)
}
```

---

In `main`, the `.dropWhile(…).next` would be more clearly written as `.find(…)`.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  triangleNumbers.find(nFactors(_) > 500).foreach(println)
}
```

Comment: Great review!! Thanks a lot. Now to read up on `scan`, `find` etc :)